# Understanding the concept of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let the subspace $S=\{(x, y, z) \in R^3; x = -2z \}$
>
> a) Determine its dimension and a basis B of S;
>
> b) Complete B such that it becomes a basis M of $R^3$.

$\operatorname{dim}(S) = 2$ because there are two free variables, but how to determine a basis $B$ for $S$? Does the vector have to belong to $S$? I think so. What about $M$? Does the third vector have to belong to $S$? I don't think so, otherwise $B$ would not generate $R^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a typical vector would normally be written as $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ but we can make a substitution here using $x=-2z$ so that our subspace vectors are written as $\begin{bmatrix}-2z\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$. From here we separate the variables using addition then factor out the variables using scalar multiplication as follows. $$\begin{bmatrix}-2z\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\y\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-2z\\0\\z\end{bmatrix}=y\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Which gives us the basis vectors  $\{\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\}$. Since there are two of them the subspace is two dimensional as you deduced from the number of free variables.

To give a complete basis for $R^3$ you'll need an additional vector not in the subspace spanned by these two. I would suggest picking a vector at random because the probability that it will be in the subspace is zero so you'll find one quickly. You just have to show it's not in the subspace to make it linearly independent of the other two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $dim(S)=2$. Here is a basis for $B$:

$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$

The basis does not span $R^3$ but it is a basis for $S$. To complete $B$ for $R^3$ just find one more vector that is orthogonal to the above two.